# Cluster a list of geographic points by distance and constraints

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, latitude-longitude, hdbscan

I have a delivery app, and I want to group orders (each order has a lat and lng coordinates) by location proximity (linear distance) and constraints like max orders and max total products (each order has an amount of products) inside a group.

For proximity grouping I used DBSCAN

```
coordinates = [[lat,lng],[lat,lng]],[lat,lng]],[lat,lng]],[lat,lng]]]
distance_matrix = squareform(pdist(coordinates, (lambda u,v: haversine(u,v))))

#eps=0.1 => 100m radius, 50m linear
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.1, min_samples=2, metric='precomputed')
results = db.fit(distance_matrix)
```

How can I add constraints in this functionality?

Is there anyway of doing this by using something else than DBSCAN or HDBSCAN ?

Comment: Whats your constraints?

Comment: @GilseungAhn max orders inside a group and max products inside a group

Comment: Well.. In this case, you need to develop a mathematical model for the clustering with constraints and solve it. In addition, is there an objective such as the number of clusters to be minimized?

Comment: @GilseungAhn Ideally will be to respect all the constraints and have minimum clusters.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.  I suppose it can be done a bunch of different ways.  Here is one solution for you to condsider.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import csv


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\properties_2017.csv')
# df.head(10)
df = df.head(10000)

df.shape


df.dropna(axis=0,how='any',subset=['latitude','longitude'],inplace=True)

# Variable with the Longitude and Latitude
X=df.loc[:,['parcelid','latitude','longitude']]
X.head(10)

K_clusters = range(1,10)
kmeans = [KMeans(n_clusters=i) 

for i in K_clusters]
Y_axis = df[['latitude']]
X_axis = df[['longitude']]
score = [kmeans[i].fit(Y_axis).score(Y_axis)

for i in range(len(kmeans))] # Visualize
plt.plot(K_clusters, score)
plt.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.title('Elbow Curve')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 10, init ='k-means++')
kmeans.fit(X[X.columns[1:3]]) # Compute k-means clustering.X['cluster_label'] = kmeans.fit_predict(X[X.columns[1:3]])centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_ # Coordinates of cluster centers.labels = kmeans.predict(X[X.columns[1:3]]) # Labels of each pointX.head(10)

X['cluster_label'] = kmeans.fit_predict(X[X.columns[1:3]])
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_ # Coordinates of cluster centers.
labels = kmeans.predict(X[X.columns[1:3]]) # Labels of each pointX.head(10)

X.head(5)

X = X[['parcelid','cluster_label']]
X.head(5)


clustered_data = df.merge(X, left_on='parcelid', right_on='parcelid')
clustered_data.head(5)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centers)


X=df.loc[:,['parcelid','latitude','longitude']]
X.plot.scatter(x = 'latitude', y = 'longitude', c=labels, s=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c='red', s=200, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]
    data = X
    labels = kmeans.labels_

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.1)
plt.scatter(data.iloc[:, 1], data.iloc[:, 2], c=kmeans.labels_, cmap='rainbow') 

for label, x, y in zip(labels, data.iloc[:, 1], data.iloc[:, 2]):
    plt.annotate(
        label,
        xy=(x, y), xytext=(-20, 20),
        textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom',
        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.5', fc='red', alpha=0.5),
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0'))

plt.show()

# labels pointing to each data point (this is a big jumbled together; you should probably select fewer data points to analyze).
```

[image]

Reference:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/clustering-gps-co-ordinates-forming-regions-4f50caa7e4a1

Data source:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/zillow-prize-1/data

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think the model you want should be developed from the scratch.

Your question can be modeled as following optimization model.

Objective function: minimize the number of clusters, K
Constraint 
(1) The size of every cluster is equal or smaller than S (parameter)
(2) The number of orders in every cluster is equal or smaller than O (parameter)
(3) For a sample x and its cluster Ck, dist(x, Ck) be the minimum among dist(x, C1), dist(x, C2), ..., dist(x, CK).

Solving this problem would require a lot of efforts...